# Seaborn pairwise matrix of hexbin jointplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to produce a matrix of pairwise plots comparing distributions ([something like this](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html#scatterplot-matrix)). Since I have many points I want to use a hexbin plot to reduce time and plot complexity.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row="sex")
g.map(sns.jointplot, "total_bill", "tip", kind="hex")
plt.show()
```

Nevertheless, instead of creating the matrix of plots it creates several plots independently in various windows.

I also thought of using `seaborn.pairplot` to produce this but I can not pass `"hex"` as a value to `kind`.

Comment: Yep i see this too using seaborn 0.7.1. i'm not sure why FacetGrid does not work with a jointplot.

Comment: I'm suffering from this same behavior and am not sure if I am doing something wrong - it creates the matrix of plots, empty, and then plots my normal jointplot in sequence after the matrix.

Comment: This comes from the fact that jointplot is a figure-level function and plots in its own figure, as opposed to a function that plots in a given axis.
In the below answer, mwaskom creates uses another figure-level function (FacetGrid) and maps to its axes a function that plots in the previously create axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the last example in the [tutorial on using custom functions](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html#mapping-custom-functions-onto-the-grid) with `FacetGrid`, which I'll reproduce here:

```
def hexbin(x, y, color, **kwargs):
    cmap = sns.light_palette(color, as_cmap=True)
    plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=15, cmap=cmap, **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, hue="time", col="time", size=4)
g.map(hexbin, "total_bill", "tip", extent=[0, 50, 0, 10])
```

[image]

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the observed counter-behaviour in case one passes the hue as `col` instead.