# Pairplot using a hexbin

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I would like to do a pairplot for all columns in my DataFrame; however instead of the scatter plot, I would like to produce hexbin plots (so I can better see density of points).

sns.pairplot doesn't have this option, I was wondering how it would be possible?

Comment: You mean something [like this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/hexbin_marginals.html?highlight=hexbin)? M aybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495093/hexbin-plot-in-pairgrid-with-seaborn) is also what you're looking for? A picture of the current and expected output would help significantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paitplot plots two kinds of plot in a single canvas for all possible pairs of variable

1. Distribution Plot which is diagonal plots. You can set it by passing argument `diag_kind : {‘auto’, ‘hist’, ‘kde’}, optional`
2. Scatter Plots which are off-diagonal plots. Set it by using `kind : {‘scatter’, ‘reg’}, optional`

[See here for more information.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)

The kind of plot which you want, you need to use `sns.jointplot`. You can use it as follows as suggested by @cripcate in the comment.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline  #extra attention at this line

sns.set(style="ticks")

rs = np.random.RandomState(11)
x = rs.gamma(2, size=1000)
y = -.5 * x + rs.normal(size=1000)

sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="#4CB391")
```

Comment: OP wants a pairplot, not a jointplot. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495093/hexbin-plot-in-pairgrid-with-seaborn) from the comments shows how to do it. There wouldn't be any need to repeat that solution anyways.

Comment: Kindly, see first part of the proposed solution which clearly shows  that sns.pairplot do not have hex kind. So I just affirmed nothing to be offended.

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: ohh... my bad... Thanks for pointing it out. I had just visited the official seaborn page. Thanks.