# Pair plot with heat maps (possibly logarithmic)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How to create a pair plot in Python like the following:
[image]
but with *heat maps* instead of points (or instead of a "hex bin" plot)? Having the possibility of instead displaying logarithmic heat map counts would be an added bonus. (Histograms on the diagonal would be perfectly fine.)

By "heat map", I mean a 2D histogram of the counts, displayed like [Seaborn's](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) or [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) heat maps:

[image]

Using Pandas, seaborn, or matplotlib would be great (maybe plot.ly).

I tried naive variations of the following, to no avail:

```
pairplot = sns.PairGrid(data)  # sns = seaborn
pairplot.map_offdiag(sns.kdeplot)  # Off-diagnoal heat map wanted instead!
pairplot.map_diag(plt.hist)  # plt = matplotlib.pyplot
```

(the above uses a Kernel Density Estimator, which I do not want; a hex bin grid can also be obtained with Pandas, but I am looking instead for a "square" 2D histogram and Matplotlib's `hist2d()` didn't work).

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to be shown in the heatmap.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31385375/6454042

Comment: @mwaskom Good point: I updated the question (I meant heat maps displaying the _counts_ of data points, i.e. 2D histograms).

Comment: @Michael Your pointing to "hex bin" maps, which are similar but with hexes. The question is specifically about something different: "square" 2D histograms.

Comment: Then you want `plt.hist2d`.

Comment: Indeed. Using it directly as in the example in the question (instead of sns.kdeplot) failed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key to your answer is the matplotlib function `plt.hist2d`, which plots counts within rectangular bins using a color scale (a "heatmap"). Its API is almost compatible with `PairGrid`, but not quite, because it doesn't know how to handle a `color=` kwarg. This is easily solved by writing a thin wrapper function. Also if you want the colormap to logarithmically map counts, that's easily accomplished with a matplotlib `LogNorm`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
sns.set_style("white")
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    

g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g.map_diag(plt.hist, bins=20)

def pairgrid_heatmap(x, y, **kws):
    cmap = sns.light_palette(kws.pop("color"), as_cmap=True)
    plt.hist2d(x, y, cmap=cmap, cmin=1, **kws)

g.map_offdiag(pairgrid_heatmap, bins=20, norm=LogNorm())
```

[image]

Comment: The clean handling of keyword arguments is a nice touch!

Answer (score 8):

Preparation:

```
%matplotlib inline #for jupyter notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
```

New answer:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_upper(plt.scatter,marker='+')
g = g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="hot",shade=True)
g = g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, shade=True)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(iris)
g = g.map_upper(plt.scatter)
g = g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="hot",shade=True)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist)
sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is using a Kernel Density Estimator, which close to what I was giving in the code of the question and is not what I am looking for.