# scatter_matrix with 2D histograms for pair plots?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas `scatter_matrix` to make pair plots, with the code below.  The problem is that the data set is quite large, making the process quite slow (and the figures bulky unless rasterizing is used).  Is there some way to replace the off-diagonal scatterplots with 2D histograms?

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, marker='.', hist_kwds={'bins': 100, 'log': True}, alpha=0.2, rasterized=True)
```

I am aware of seaborn `PairGrid` [Pair plot with heat maps (possibly logarithmic)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924280/pair-plot-with-heat-maps-possibly-logarithmic), but that has a few drawbacks, including I can't figure out how to make the 1D diagonal histograms use a vertical log scale.